'Any of us who becomes' or 'Any of us who become'?
Is the singular or plural version of become or becomes appropriate when writing: any of us who become aware of something should act?

Any is normally plural unless the context forces singular. Hence a teacher would say: Any of you who are still confused can see me after class. Or force the singular with Any student who is still confused can see me after class.

Yes and while '… who becomes' or '… become rich' makes no never-mind, that's only because rich is a non-count condition.
Consider instead, 'Any of us who becomes a judge…' or 'Any of us who become judges'.

There are 337 000 results in a Google search for "any of us who become" as against 5 for "any of us who becomes". The pronoun 'any' is far more commonly used with a plural verb-form, even with the cushioning 'of us'. (There is though a minority who use 'any' to mean 'any one of [the]', with a singular verb-form.)
Using 'any'
as a determiner rather than a pronoun makes
"any one of us who becomes" available (101 000 raw results).
I'd avoid unmatched agreement with count-noun usages or probably-count-noun  usages such as

?? ... any of us who become president

(use '... any one [of us] who becomes president').

Internet searches can be proof of usage folly or not but not grammar.

'Language is ever-evolving, according to Mignon Fogarty, self-titled “Grammar Girl” and author of Grammar Girl Presents the Ultimate Writing Guide for Students. She explains that grammar rules are often in a consistent state of flux; they shift in line with cultural convention as they adapt to new norms.' [ Molly Pennington; RD] Looks like these people believe that descriptivism ultimately determines even grammaticality.

I agree completely.

So internet searches can provide strong evidence of acceptability, even where grammar is involved. 'Working mens clubs' for instance is used far more often than 'working men's clubs'.

Mignon Fogarty? Going for the scholarly stuff eh, @EdwinAshworth? A quick check on Google reveals 14.6m hits for "working mens club" vs 197m hits for the genitive "Working men's clubs". A huge difference.

I get 415 000 vs 311 000, BillJ. Not so huge a difference; I'll admit I'm speaking from local knowledge though. I'll adjust to ''Working mens clubs' for instance is used at least nearly as often as 'working men's clubs'.  It certainly shows a change occurring at the moment. // You could be _con_structive by adding a more prestigious (doubtless not more eloquent) variant on the quote. Or perhaps you think it's wrong?

No, internet searches are not really proof of acceptability if you are editing a written publication, for example. And each of those hits suggests, it's the poster who made the decision to write/post working men's clubs or working men clubs. You still have to decide for yourself. So, it isn't a numbers game.

ELU isn't aimed primarily at people editing written publications. Deciding for oneself isn't a crime, but doing what most (or a large proportion of) people do is usually far more sensible than being hyperprescriptive. The point is, even grammar isn't fixed.

Internet searches aren't proof of usage; often they match things other than the exact phrase, and they can include synonyms or singular/plural forms. You need to look at results, or use a more reliable search e.g. on a proper corpus.
